# Movie with giant creatures invading our planet from another dimension or portal, maybe based on Stephen King novel

Tags: story-identification, movie

There's an American movie, I believe it's probably 5-12 years old, that is suspense with horror elements. The thing I remember most about it is the end, when it is revealed that there are huge bizarre looking creatures of gigantic proportions that have arrived accidentally on our planet from another dimension through some sort of portal. These creatures are stomping around causing all kinds of havoc, crushing cars, killing people, etc. I think that it's based on a Stephen King novel, but I don't know for sure. What's the name of this movie?

The creatures are kind of like dinosaurs, in the shape and size, land-dwelling, but their features unlike anything of this earth.

Comment: Are there giant robots fighting them? Aside from the age and possible Stephen King link, this sounds like *Pacific Rim*.

Comment: live action or cartoon/anime?

Comment: not Pacific Rim. It's an older film. Live action.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnE64DbnUzY

Comment: @phantom42 If there aren't giant robots, then why bother?

Comment: Was there definitely more than one giant creature? Do you remember any descriptions of the human characters involved? *Cloverfield* had one giant creature destroying everything, and the age fits. There were small parasites on the creature, but they weren't a big threat. They never 100% identified the origin of the creature in the movie, though.

Comment: Possibly [_The Langoliers_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112040/?ref_=ttgf_gf_tt). I believe they "eat" time itself, but also crush stuff.

It's older than you indicate, but I believe the monsters' visible form had dinosaur-like heads.

Comment: I don't think it was The Langoliers. I'm sure the one I saw was a movie, not a mini-series.

Answer (score 15):

I believe you are remembering [The Mist.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mist_%28film%29)

It came out in 2007.

Comment: Maybe this is it. I didn't think it was The Mist at first, but coming across the following picture jogged my memory: http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Creatures_of_the_Mist?file=Behemoth.png

Comment: yeah, those huge ones are only shown at the end of the movie, that is what made me think of it. They are hinted at before that but not shown.

Comment: I'm wondering though ... isn't at the end of the movie where the one guy kills everybody in the vehicle and doesn't have enough bullets left in the gun to kill himself, thinking the creatures were going to get him. This is just in time the mist to clear and to find the troops come marching up the road. They would have been saved if they'd only given it a few more minutes time. This would be very memorable as it is a *very* gut wrenching twist to the movie. Just saying.

Comment: Pretty sure that is how the short story ends. The movie alludes to that ending but doesn't actually show it.

Comment: @Justin C - No, the [original short story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mist) doesn't end that way, there's no group suicide but also no eradication of the mist by the military, it's just left open-ended with them driving away from the supermarket through a now-monster-filled world, and hearing the world "Hartford" on the radio, giving them some slight hope of a refuge for survivors.

Comment: @Hypnosifl you and Paulster2 are right. That is how the movie ended, not the novella.

Comment: Not just if they waited a few more minutes. One of the people saved by the military at the end of the movie was... dun dun dunnnn, the woman who left to save her kids at the very start of the movie.